# Can only install one of error when installing telegram-bot/api

Tags: composer-php, telegram-bot

I'm trying to install telegram-bot/api on Centos7/PHP5.6, I'm getting this error when running "php composer.phar require telegram-bot/api"

```
# php composer.phar require telegram-bot/api
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^2.3 for telegram-bot/api
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.0, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.1, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.10, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.11, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.12, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.13, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.2, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.3, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.4, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.5, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.6, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.7, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.8, 1.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.9, 1.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for telegram-bot/api 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by telegram-bot/api[1.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for telegram-bot/api ^2.3 -> satisfiable by telegram-bot/api[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Edit: As olibiaz suggested, I'm adding composer.json, which I've downloaded using this repo https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api:

```
{
    "name": "telegram-bot/api",
    "description": "PHP Wrapper for Telegram Bot API",
    "keywords": [
        "php",
        "telegram",
        "bot",
        "bot api"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Ilya Gusev",
            "email": "mail@igusev.ru",
            "homepage": "https://php-cat.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php" : ">=5.5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "~4.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
        "codeception/codeception": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TelegramBot\\Api\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TelegramBot\\Api\\Test\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried specifying the version of telegram-bot/api to use v2.3.9 but I still receive the same error: - Can only install one of: telegram-bot/api[v2.3.9, 1.0.x-dev].

I don't know what else I'm missing, I've already spent a lot of time looking for how to troubleshoot

Comment: it should help to see your composer.json

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it changing the name in composer.json to something like:

```
  "name": "telegram-bot/api_project",
```

Comment: This is not a solution, you're just using composer in a wrong way. You should not download project from GitHub, just run `php composer.phar require telegram-bot/api` in root of **your** project.